# Problem of when changing a curve point's position all other curve points start to rotate(tilt)

Tags: modeling

When a curve has Extrude in Curve Properties often this problem occurs. I really want all    other curve points stay the tilt they were. Is there any way to do it?

[image]

The system link this question to a similar question of which the answer is to use Z-up under Twist Method of Curve Properties. Z-up does work comparing to the default, however Z-up also has glitches that cannot be fixed in this case. If I use Z-up it would be looking like this and no matter how you change the tilt of the very bottom curve point and the two above, the overtwisted shape won't disappear

[image]

Comment: Hello, I can't reproduce what you show, could you please share your file?

Comment: Sure, [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=DRylQA2o" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/DRylQA2o/)

Comment: what ar eyou doing in the first picture, if I move the vertex, I don't have the same result: https://zupimages.net/up/22/47/89f3.gif

Comment: Yes it's because the project file has set Twist Mode to Z-up. If you change the Twist Mode in the Curve Properties to default which is Minimum you would have the result of the first image